# emacs delete directory recursively?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I was searching through for a way to copy/delete directory trees... dired seems to have 
dired-copy-file-recursive (though sans documentation) and a search on 'recursive' also returns:

```
tramp-handle-dired-recursive-delete-directory is a compiled Lisp
function in `tramp.el'.

(tramp-handle-dired-recursive-delete-directory FILENAME)

Recursively delete the directory given.
This is like `dired-recursive-delete-directory' for Tramp files.
```

But I can't find `dired-recursive-delete-directory` anywhere! Anyone know what's going on? Thanks ~

**Edit** Thanks all for the responses. The computer I have has 23.1 installed (it's in a remote location with no internet so installations/upgrades are a pain) but I did find `dired-delete-file` has a recursive option that accomplishes this task (had to activate with `(require 'dired)`). I look forward to upgrading to 23.2 on my personal machine though!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. `dired-recursive-delete-directory` is in `dired.el` (in line 3660 in my version). It's not available in your minibuffer because it isn't interactive, but it's used when executing `dired-expunge-deletions` (normally bound to `x`). Is your installation missing `dired`?

Comment: Actually, I do have dired.el but don't see `dired-recursive-delete-directory` or `dired-expunge-deletions` in there. I did however find that `dired-delete-file` has a recursive options that works for directories! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [this section](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Create_002fDelete-Dirs.html) of the Emacs Lisp manual. This refers to the latest stable Emacs version(23.2). It's always a good idea to use it (if possible) anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In Emacs 23.2 the following are available (I copy from [Emacs 23.2 news](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/NEWS.23.2))

> - Changes to file-manipulation functions
> - `delete-directory' has an optional parameter RECURSIVE.
> - New function `copy-directory', which copies a directory recursively.

For complete documentation you can check the [Emacs Lisp Reference](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Create_002fDelete-Dirs.html) but of course C-h f is always your friend.

Answer (score 1):

This will let you mark directories for recursive deletion in dired:

```
(setq dired-recursive-deletes 'top)
```

Dired will prompt for confirmation.

Comment: Thanks, but not for programming?